# grouping data with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need some special grouping like this;

```
<section class="white">
<p>1. row</p>
<p>2. row</p>
</section>
<section class="white">
<p>3.row</p>
<p>4.row</p>
</section>
<section class="white">
<p>5.row</p>
<p>6.row</p>
</section>
```

i added ng-repeat to section tag like getNumbers(3) method for items. and inside section another ng-repeat for row with limitTo and indexTo filters but it did not work like what i want.

Anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Don't understand what you need. Please explain more, provide code...

Comment: Can you share your code with me.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this code works;

```
<section class="white" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]">
    <div class="container-c">
        <div class="col-1-fm" ng-repeat="item in items | startFrom: (i * 3) | limitTo:3">
            <h5>{{item.categoryName}}</h5>
            <div class="img-container" class="crPointer">
                <img ng-src="{{item.image}}" border="0" />
            </div>
            <h2 class="crPointer">{{item.title}}</h2>
            <p class="fcWhite crPointer">
                {{item.description}}
            </p>
            <div class="action">
                <a href="">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> View
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

in javascript;

```
mbApp.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});
```

but it seems some kind of trick :)

Is there a better solution? May be with ng-repeat-start & ng-repeat-end?